# Generate a html report from Trivy

Tags: trivy

I'm trying to generate a **HTML** report from Trivy.  On the [example](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.17.2/examples/report/) page, they provide `trivy image --format template --template "@contrib/html.tpl" -o report.html golang:1.12-alpine`.  When I run this, I get the following error,

`FATAL  report error: unable to write results: failed to initialize template writer: error retrieving template from path: open contrib/html.tpl: no such file or directory`

Based on the documentation, It looks like this is a **default template** so I'm assuming it's included. My logic here is that there is no "/" following the "@" in the template path.

I'm currently on version 0.41.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not install trivy from RPM and had no files other than a solid trivy binary of a few 10 MBs. Downloaded the html.tpl template from their github repo https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/blob/main/contrib/html.tpl and placed it in `/usr/bin/html.tpl` and used the command line: `trivy image --format template --template "@/usr/bin/html.tpl" -o report.html image-name`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what operating system you're using, but on Kali Linux I do the following:

```
trivy fs FOLDER_PATH --format -template --template 
      "@/usr/share/trivy/templates/html.tpl" --output NAME_OF_FOLDER.html
```

I like customizing the .tpl file to generate a html page to my liking, so I generally copy the file somewhere else and edit it.

`--template "@/home/user/Desktop/html.tpl"` (or wherever you wanna put it)

The example you link is from old documentation. Here's something newer that might help: https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.41/docs/configuration/reporting/#default-templates

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for 0.41 you need to find out the path where the templates are saved on your system. I also use the standard template and need to set **"@/usr/local/share/trivy/templates/html.tpl"** as path. I guess it depends on your operating system and the way you've installed trivy. I run it on a centOS 7 System

Information from the Documentation:
[image]

Example command from documentation: `$ trivy image --format template --template "@/path/to/template" golang:1.12-alpine -o your_output.html`

Answer (score 0):

First, we should find the file in your system "html.tpl". I am using a mac and when I ran the below find command

> find / -name html.tpl

**output:**
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/...../.trivy/contrib/html.tpl

I passed the html.tpl path in the command

trivy image --format template --template **html path** -o report.html **image name**

It worked.

Comment: You need to append @ to the html path to get this working. Like  ```trivy image --format template --template "@/usr/bin/html.tpl" -o report.html image-name```